# str_replace, gives me the wrong result Only when numerals are in it

Tags: php, str-replace

```
//post data
$post = $_POST['username'];

//str replace
$print = str_replace([1,2,3,4,5], ['4A','6B','7C','2D','6F'], $post);

//prints result
echo "{\"username\":\"" . $print . "\"}";
```

str replace works fine when it's just alpha (example: `TEST!@#test = 7160767124452671607671` which is just perfect, but as soon as digits come into play things get messy `$print` should output `{"username":"4A6B7C2D6F"}` if input `12345` the current output is `{"username":"2DA6B7C2D6F"}`

Comment: Please show us clear input and the expected output with that input.  I don't follow what you are trying to do here.

Comment: expected output `{"username":"4A6B7C2D6F"}`if input `12345` the current output is `{"username":"2DA6B7C2D6F"}`

Comment: `1` becomes `4A` then the `4` is replaced with `2D` so you get the `2DA`.

Comment: I see, I have had it in order, which worked fine if it's just numeral. The problem is I have alpha in my actual code, as well as symbols. That's why things are getting messy.

Comment: Without your actual code, just about any answer to this may be wrong. Please provide real-world requirements and examples

Comment: Also, **never roll your own JSON**. Use `echo json_encode(['username' => $print]);` instead

Comment: I have gave real world examples and requirements, just because I haven't uploaded an entire thing, that has lots of stuff not needed for this question, I snipped it down to what you need to answer my question.

Comment: So what exactly does _"I have alpha in my actual code, as well as symbols"_ mean? Are you or are you not **only** trying to replace digits 1 through 5 with 4A, 6B, 7C, 2D, 6F?

Comment: Yes I am, But it goes along with my alpha too, why do you think I uploaded what TEST!@#test = to, becauuse it's in there... is it required to answer this question? no it's not.

Comment: You have not defined the relationship between `TEST!@#test` and `7160767124452671607671`. There are no digits in `TEST!@#test` so how can a replacement operation that replaces 1 through 5 affect that string at all? I only ask as one possible (but probably incorrect) answer would be to re-order the find / replace arrays so they don't conflict but this would only be possible if your were **only** replacing 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5

Comment: `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?` it's been answered, I won't be responding no more. Thankyou for your help!

Comment: @RazuRazu look, you're already sitting on 2 downvotes. I'm just trying to help you not have that happen again. Take care

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I found some information regarding your issue in the official PHP.net documentation.

> **Caution**
>
> **Replacement order gotcha**
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a
>   previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also
>   the examples in this document.

In your case it's first replacing the `1` with `4A` and then replacing the `4` in `4A` with `2D` resulting in `2DA` and after that it seems to be replacing everything correctly.

Happy coding!

**EDIT:** Using strtr as illustrated in Paul's answer will give you the result you desire.

Comment: This is a nice explanation of the problem but doesn't exactly provide a solution.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find a good way to solve it. I thought about using strtr like you did in your answer, but couldn't recall that an array could be used for replacements.

Comment: That is not my answer

Comment: Woops! Seems like I misread the name. My bad. I've updated my answer pointing to Paul's answer for the solution.